# Dart Multiple Translations

Tags: internationalization, dart

If in your application you import a package, which has a translation 
and in your application create a translation, you get:

> Duplicated library name 'messages_all'. library messages_all;

when using the **generate_from_arb** functionality.
This applies also to the library in the translated files, e.g. messages_es

The cause is that in generate_localized.dart, the library name(s) are hardcoded.

Is there a good work around ... other than renaming the translation libraries?
... and what exact impact does it have?

Is there a "best practice" for translating multiple libraries?